# Form is not closing

Tags: html, forms

I have a form on a HTML document with this header

```
<form target="_blank" action=""  id="form-find-your-program">
```

and I have an input button within it

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" class="readmore" value="Submit">
```

and then the closing tag after the input button:

```
</form>
```

The problem is that the form is not closing as I assume because I have another form after it, that is submitting with this one.
This is the complete code:

```
<div class="row">
        <find_program_form_home>
        <div class="custom form_colors_invert">
        <form target="_blank" action=""  id="form-find-your-program">
                <div class="six columns noleftmargin">          
                    <h5 class="sidebartitle">Find Your Program</h5> 
                </div>
                <div class="four columns">
                    <select class="custom dropdown" id="findProgramSelectProgram" required="" title="Select a Program">
                    <option value="">Select a Program</option>
                    <option value="Undergraduate">Undergraduate</option>
                    <option value="Graduate">Graduate</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="four columns">
                    <select class="custom dropdown" id="AreaOfStudyAll" required="" title="Area of Study">
                        <option value="">Area of Study</option>

                        <!--<option class="dd-undergraduate" disabled="disabled" value="">Undergraduate</option> -->
                        <option class="dd-undergraduate" value="something.html">something</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="four columns">
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" class="readmore" value="Submit">
                </div>
        </form>
        </find_program_form_home>
        </div>
    <div class="six columns noleftmargin">
            <h5 class="sidebartitle"><a href="online_course_catalog.html">Online Course Catalog</a></h5>
            <p>
            Search our registration catalog to find upcoming online courses.
            </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: what is <find_program_form_home>? are you using any pollyfill functionallity?

Comment: I see only 1 form in that code. Also, what do you mean by "not closing"?

Comment: Can you post the full code, including both forms?

Comment: you need to flip these two lines of code --> </find_program_form_home></div> , you are closing the new tag off before the div  and that's not the proper order according to the code posted

Comment: I flipped them nothing changed, what I mean is that the form is not closing because when it submits, it causes the second form after it to submit also.